# Replace Line in CSV file

Tags: c#, .net, linq, csv

I have an CSV file with 10 lines. In every line some data: Id, Data, number, etc.
I wanna replace some line base on Id column. Could you take a look please and tell how I can fix it. Thanks.
my code is:

```
public static IEnumerable<Invoice> Replace(int Id, string invoice)
        {
            var replacedLine = "";
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Invoices.csv");
            var listInvoices = new List<Invoice>();

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var value = line.Split(";");

                if(Int32.Parse(value[1]) == Id) //value[1] it's Id column
                {
                    replacedLine = line.Replace(line, invoice);
                }

                if(replacedLine != "")
                    value = replacedLine.Split(";");

                var invoice1 = new Invoice()
                {
                    DateAndTimeCreation = value[0],
                    Id = Int32.Parse(value[1]),
                    Status = GetStatus(value[2]),
                    Amount = Decimal.Parse(value[3]),
                    PaymentMethod = GetPayment(value[4])
                };
                listInvoices.Add(invoice1);
            }

            File.WriteAllText("Invoices.csv", replacedLine);
            return listInvoices;
        }
```

At this moment problem is - it removing all lines and add replaced line(I got file with 1 line).
Also i tried apply:

```
File.Replace("Invoices.csv", "Invoices.csv", replacedLine);
```

Anyone could help replacing line without loosing else lines? thanks

Comment: File.WriteAllText("Invoices.csv", replacedLine); writes 1 line - it's ok. Use File.WriteAllLines (...,listInvoices)

Comment: Totally expected. You replace the content by one single line. You need to write all of it.

Comment: I'd also recommend to use one of the plenty excellent CSV libs out there. And being familiar with Invoice-Processing: Chose a separator that is more likely to not collide with content ;) In fact, I'd recommend to _not_ use CSV _at all_ if you can help it.

Comment: ^^ Why I am advising against CSV: I _had to_ use CSV as a transfer data format from our system to 3rd party systems (also invoice data) and I did not have _one_ installation where exactly this did _not_ cause any problems. Sometimes minor and resolved through configuration, but also sometimes really really nasty. And all of which could have been no prolem using XML or JSON.

Comment: 1) Regarding File.WriteAllLines(..., listInvoices) - It's not working, because listInvoices it's collection objects, not strings. 
2)@Fildor didn't get you, what do you mean "write all of it", describe please

Comment: `File.WriteAllText("Invoices.csv", replacedLine)` opens the `invoices.csv`, deletes everything in it, writes the `replacedLine`  into it (that's what you have given as an argument), and closes the file. So you have to write all of your csv content from zero, not just the replaced line.

Answer (score 1):

Approach the task by splitting it into logical parts:

1. Read the file line by line
2. Find the necessary line and replace it with a different value
3. Write the data back

So:

```
// setting up stuff
var path = "Invoices.csv";
var id = 1;
var regex = new Regex("^[^;]+;" + id); // regex magic
var replacement = "foo bar"; // add value here

// doing the work
var originalLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
var replacedLines = originalLines.Select(x => regex.IsMatch(x) ? replacement : x);
File.WriteAllLines(path, replacedLines);
```

It should be noted that this will only work with your particular CSV. In general, the format is much more tricky. For example, just splitting by `;` is dangerous because there can be strings containing the semicolon as an escaped value. If you need any serious processing of CSV data, I suggest you use a specialized parser like [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper).

**UPDATE**: using a regular expression instead of `StartsWith` due to the format of the input data.

Going into details about regular expressions is out of scope for this question, so I will just explain what this one does:

- `^` = start of string
- `[^;]` = anything except a semicolon
- `+` = the previous statement (in brackets) can be repeated 1 or more times
- `id` - the literal value of the ID to search for

Regular expressions are tightly bound to the particular data you expect them to work on, so this will probably require modifications if you would want to apply it to a different CSV.

Comment: So, I changed to: 
`var path = "Invoices.csv";
            var id = 1;
            var replacement = invoice; //invoice= "Id=100"

            var originalLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            var replacedLines = originalLines.Select(x => x.StartsWith(id + ";") ? replacement : x);
            File.WriteAllLines(path, replacedLines);`. It's still not replaced. 
As I can see replacedLine wasn't change. Here some issue.

Comment: @КириллФилободченко apparently the predicate did not match (I see now that in your data ID is the second column, not first, and the first is dynamic) - so you need to use a regular expression instead. I will update the answer.

Comment: nothing changed. After your update it's paste the same 10 lines, it wasn't replaced :(

Comment: @КириллФилободченко Please provide a sample of the data - the first 3 columns of the first line